# Set Application Icon Using Canonical Quickly

Tags: gtk, icons, ubuntu-12.04, ubuntu-unity, canonical-quickly

Is there a simple way to set an application's icon using `canoncial-quickly`? I have tried setting the icon file of the main window within `Glade`, but the application **still uses one of the stock GTK icons** as its main icon in `Unity` on `Ubuntu 12.04 LTS`.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the directory with your Quickly Ubuntu application in it. Let's say it's called myproj. Inside myproj is a directory named data. Inside data is a directory named media. And in there you should see a graphic file named myproj.svg. Replace myproj.svg with a scalable vector graphics image of your choice. You can either download an svg off the web, or create one for yourself in Inkscape. The next time you run your application, it will pick up myproj.svg as its icon.